# C#:Saving image to folder

Tags: c#, save

HI. I know this is simple question but when I use

```
 FirstPersonTestImage.Save(IIdComboBox.Text + "-" + i + ".jpg");
```

it works and saves file to folder where is the .exe file . But I want to save it to specific folder like  /photo/IO-66/  and tryed to use

```
 String StudentPath = PhotoPath + IGroupNoComboBox.Text + "/" + IIdComboBox.Text + "/" + IIdComboBox.Text + "-" + i + ".jpg";

 FirstPersonTestImage.Save(StudentPath);
```

BUt it gives

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

How can I solve this problem? Is is about folder path ? or using  "/" ?

**EDIT**

Here My code for creating and checking existing or not folder

```
  if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(PhotoPath + "/" + IGroupNoComboBox.Text.ToString().Trim()))
            {

               Directory.CreateDirectory(PhotoPath + "/" + IGroupNoComboBox.Text.ToString().Trim());


            }

             if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(PhotoPath + "/" + IGroupNoComboBox.Text.ToString().Trim()+ "/" + IIdComboBox.Text.ToString().Trim() + "/"))
            {

                Directory.CreateDirectory(PhotoPath + "/" + IGroupNoComboBox.Text.ToString().Trim()+"/" + IIdComboBox.Text.ToString().Trim() + "/");

            }
```

Comment: you could check that out, just use the debugger

Comment: use `Path.Combine()` or replace `"/"` by `"\\"`

Comment: arrgh! nightmare.  Why would you not create the path once and assign it to a variable then use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the path together manually, just use the `IO.Path.Combine` method and you don't have to worry about it.

If you're in VS2010 you can just call it with multiple parameters and otherwise you'll have to have nested calls.

Comment: Should I  use Combine like  IO.Path.Combine(PhotoPath,IGroupNoComboBox.Text + "/" + IIdComboBox.Text + "/" + IIdComboBox.Text + "-" + i + ".jpg") ?

Comment: `Combine` glues together different directories, so whenever you use / you can use `Combine` to combine them instead, you'll still have to create the filename manually as you currently do. As Thorsten says, look at the help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142.aspx

Comment: I used Path.Combine and it does not worked and i release that   instead of " - " ,I should use " _ " . And then worked. Also with out Path.Combine works too , but less mess is every time good ))